# C# WinForms toggle button "enabled" property based on listView.selectedItems.count

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, button, toggle

I'd like to be able to have a button ONLY enabled when a certain listview has a selected item... such as `listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0`

I can enable a button once a listViewItem is selected... but I can't figure out how to UNenable once the user clicks away from the listView.

Is there any "ListViewItem DeActivate" function?  I've looked around but can't find anything.

Comment: you can use **LostFocus** event :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the SelectedIndexChanged event ...

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code i am writing this code by supposing that in list at **0 index** you have nothing to select or it has **--select--** value

```
  private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count>0)
      {
          //this code will disable the button if it has any selection
          button1.Enabled =false;
      }
      if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count==0)
      {
          //this code will enable the button if it has any selection
          button1.Enabled =true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Lostfocus event and then try something like this.

```
private void Lost_Focus_Ev(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        My_button.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Everytime a user selects another control the button will be disabled. You can renable the button when the listview is re selected.